# Insert function class vector c++

Tags: c++

I am fairly new to c++ and I am having trouble with getting my insert function to implement the right way. I would need to get my output to match with my school's. I feel like I am close but do not know what to do from here on. I would certainly require your expertise on this issue. Thank you in advance!

School's Output(Correct one):

```
Empty array:
(size=0, capacity=0)
push_back 5 floats:
0  (size=1, capacity=1)
0   1.41  (size=2, capacity=2)
0   1.41   2.82  (size=3, capacity=4)
0   1.41   2.82   4.24  (size=4, capacity=4)
0   1.41   2.82   4.24   5.65  (size=5, capacity=8)
insert(3, 99):
0   1.41   2.82     99   4.24   5.65  (size=6, capacity=8)
insert(0, 98):
98      0   1.41   2.82     99   4.24   5.65  (size=7, capacity=8)
insert(6, 97):
98      0   1.41   2.82     99   4.24     97   5.65  (size=8, capacity=8)
```

My Output:

```
********** TestInsert1 **********
Empty array:
(size=0 capacity=2)
push_back 5 floats:
0.00 (size=1 capacity=2)
0.00 1.41 (size=2 capacity=2)
0.00 1.41 2.82 (size=3 capacity=4)
0.00 1.41 2.82 4.24 (size=4 capacity=4)
0.00 1.41 2.82 4.24 5.65 (size=5 capacity=8)
insert(3, 99):
0.00 1.41 2.82 99.00 4.24 2.82 (size=6 capacity=8)
insert(0, 98):
98.00 -0.00 1.41 2.82 4.24 2.82 1.41 (size=7 capacity=8)
insert(6, 97):
98.00 -0.00 1.41 2.82 4.24 2.82 97.00 1.41 (size=8 capacity=8)
```

My header file(Consist of insert function):

```
template <typename T>
class vector 
{

private:
    T* v;
    int count;
    int capacity;
public:
void insert(int index, T number)
{
    count++;
    int j = 0;
for (int i = count; i > 0; i--){
    if (j >= index){
        v[j + 1] = v[i];
    }
    j++;
}
v[index] = number;

}

template <typename T1>
friend void Print(const vector<T1>& s);
};

template <typename T1>
void Print(const vector<T1>& s)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < s.count; i++) 
    {
    std::cout<<s.v[i]<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<< "(size=" << s.count << " " << "capacity=" << s.capacity << 
")";
    std::cout<<std::endl; 
    }
}
```

Main file:

```
void TestInsert1(void)
{
std::cout << "\n********** TestInsert1 **********\n";
cs150::vector<float> a;
std::cout << "Empty array:\n";
Print(a);

std::cout << "push_back 5 floats:\n";
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    a.push_back(i*1.412492f);
    Print(a);
}

std::cout << "insert(3, 99):\n";
a.insert(3, 99);
Print(a);
std::cout << "insert(0, 98):\n";
a.insert(0, 98);
Print(a);
std::cout << "insert(6, 97):\n";
a.insert(6, 97);
Print(a);
}
```

Comment: What is count, what is expected value of it in the beginning of `insert` function?

Comment: count is the size, sorry.

Comment: Seems the only difference between your output and your schools is the amount of precision when displaying floating point values. What does your `Print` function look like?

Comment: Just updated the on output. Added some extra details

Comment: I'll add my print function, hold on.

Comment: So I think all you need to do is add `std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2);` to the start of your `Print` function, and `#include <iomanip>` to your header file. This will cause all your floats to be printed to two decimal places.

Comment: Well, wait up, there's something i noticed too. If u were to look closely, the 99 is missing in the 2nd insert test. The one at insert(0,98). It is suppose to contain the 99 from the previous insert. but somehow its gone. Any idea why that is?

Comment: @john any idea? -To my above point.

Comment: Are you sure of how you handle the j variable? What does it mean?

Comment: @Nico238 It's resolved alr. I overcomplicated matters. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you had the right idea, but complicated it a bit. You should be moving elements by 1 from the most right element in the list, which is v[count-1], to the element at index, which is v[index], where you are putting your new number.

```
void insert(int index, T number)
{
    for (int i = count - 1; i >= index; i--) {
        v[i + 1] = v[i];
    }

    count++;
    v[index] = number;
}
```